# chrome rewrite ajax response with change close tag position

Tags: ajax, google-chrome

When i test my web site today.I can't submit the form .I checked the ajax response in chrome tools under network.
The HTML like this

```
<form><input type="image" /></form>
```

Actually the source in chrome tools under elements is

```
<form></form><input type="image" />
```

It's only happened under chrome. (IE and safari is work well)

What i can do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <form><input name="image" /><input type="image" /></form>
```

Comment: I checked my html code. It's all right .It's my mistake .I'm write a careless html sample code in my question.I had correction it .